# Blender still using CPU even when I have CUDA chosen in preferences?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

The problem is as title suggests, I selected CUDA and checked my GPU in preferences for the Cycles Render Device [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKJFH.jpg). But when I'm running my render, the CPU usage is anywhere from 88-99% and the GPU usage is around 10-15% [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrpkL.jpg). I can only imagine that Blender is still using my CPU to render the scene.
How do I fix this?

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 2):

Head over to the *Scenes* tab, and select *GPU Compute*.

[image]

PS: you can paste/upload images directly into your post.