# Eevee is using my CPU to render

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I rendered a short animation using Eevee engine, but my cpu was used 100% of the time. The temperature and fan of the cpu went crazy. How is that possible? Eevee is supposed to use OpenGL and has nothing to do with the settings in preferences, correct me if I'm wrong. I do have Cycles on GPU Compute and Cuda selected in Preferences with no CPU, but that shouldn't matter anyway. I have my both monitors plugged in the GPU display ports. It's a RTX 2070. I rendered the animation 3 times and checked the hardware with CAM and Task Manager. Why is Eevee using my CPU instead of GPU???

Comment: Please refer to this question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162264/blender-still-using-cpu-even-when-i-have-cuda-chosen-in-preferences/162265#162265

Comment: I have the Cycles engine setup just like that with GPU Compute and Cuda in Preferences. But it shouldn't matter anyway. I'm using Eevee for animation rendering and it uses my CPU 100%. How could that be? By the way, I just rendered it with Cycles and it's all good using my GPU completely.

Comment: Ah sorry, wrong link. I'll post the full answer

Comment: Make sure that Blender uses your dedicated GPU and not the integrated GPU in your CPU. This can be configured in the Nvidia control panel.

Comment: Let me check that and I will get back to you.

Comment: Simulations? Particles? Complex nodes? Number of Subdivisions? Compositing?There are quite a number of operations that are done in CPU regardless. Please describe your scene in detail.

Comment: No particles or simulations, neither complex nodes. Very simple seen with few objects in it. I wen't to Nvidia Driver Control Panel and I changed the OpenGL from Auto-Select to GPU RTX 2070. It didn't fix the problem. I did another animation one with Cycles another one with Eevee. Cycles uses up to 85% the GPU and 9-10% the CPU, Eevee does exactly the opposite. It's totally abnormal behavior from Eevee. What's happening?

Comment: Guess what. Because you mentioned the Compositing piece I checked it out. I had an Alpha Over, an RGB and a Denoise Filter. I removed the denoise filter and problem solved. The CPU doesn't go nuts anymore when rendering with Eevee. If I keep the denoise on with Cycles there is no problem with the cpu though.

Comment: what?  no i'm not

Answer (score 9):

If anybody runs into the same problem in Eevee where the cpu is overloaded while rendering check your Compositing mode and make sure you don't have a Denoise filter on. It doesn't create a problem when you render in Cycles but it does put stress on the cpu when rendering with Eevee.

Comment: Good to know, thanks :).

Comment: Why on earth would denoising ever cause issues like this?  It's either using a neural network to denoise (much faster on the GPU), or it is using a wavelet transform (again, much faster on the GPU).  This is a bug in Eevee if it is trying to do denoising on the CPU.

Comment: @whn `s/bug/missing feature/`?

Answer (score 4):

From the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/limitations.html#cpu-rendering):

> **CPU Rendering**
>
> Being a rasterization engine, Eevee only uses the power
> of the GPU to render. There is no plan to support CPU (software)
> rendering as it would be very inefficient. CPU power is still needed
> to handle high scene complexity as the geometry must be prepared by
> the CPU before rendering each frame.

In short: CPU is still needed to prep the scene, GPU is used to render it.

Comment: There is no complexity in my scene. There is no need for the CPU to kick in. The GPU is not even loaded. I wish I could send you a vid with the CAM graph to see it. It didn't happen before. It's just something new out of whack. Not sure what on planet earth is happening.